# How to manage user context in M2M microservices scenarios?

Tags: authentication, oauth, zero, trust

Imagine a scenario where you have a system consisting of multiple microservices, each responsible for a specific aspect of your application. Let's say you have a user management service, an e-commerce service, and a recommendation service.

Now, consider a situation where a user logs into your e-commerce service and starts browsing for products. To provide personalized product recommendations, your e-commerce service needs to communicate with the recommendation service, which is another microservice. This is a classic example of many-to-many (M2M) communication in a microservices architecture because multiple services are involved in serving a single user's request.

The question is, how do you effectively handle and maintain the user's context, such as their identity and preferences, as it flows through these different microservices? In other words, how can you ensure that the recommendation service knows which user is making the request and can provide relevant suggestions based on that user's history and interactions?

This scenario highlights the challenge of managing user context in M2M communication within a microservices architecture. It's essential to implement strategies and mechanisms to achieve seamless and secure user context propagation across these services.

My approach involves combining an M2M key and a user OAuth token in requests for handling user context in microservices with many-to-many (M2M) communication. The M2M key ensures secure and trusted communication between services. Meanwhile, the user OAuth token maintains the user's identity and access privileges across services.